# Deepstream 1 - n relation

Tags: deepstream.io

I'm trying to build a `user notification` using `Deepstream.io`. I'm using `deepstream.io-storage-mongodb` for storage. My data structure:

```
User
=================
id - email - others


Notication
=================
userId - notification
```

I'm try to implement [1-n modelling deepsteam tutorial](https://deepstreamhub.com/tutorials/recipes/modelling-relational-data/#1-n-relation). But I can't understand how can I do this. How can I store pointer or how can I point towards a `List` ? Or how can I implement notification using `deepstream` ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try as like as given below (I'm using `JS`):

**Receive Notication**

```
var client = deepstream( 'localhost:6020' );
client.login();

// Unique Identification for user
let uniqueId = `userId:${userId}`;

// Mongodb collection : Notification 
statusRecord = client.record.getList("Notification/" + uniqueId);

statusRecord.subscribe(function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(name) {
        var record = client.record.getRecord(name);
        record.whenReady(function(r) {
           // all notification
           console.log( "r ==> ", r.get() );
        });
    });
});
```

**Send Notification**

```
const ds = deepstream( 'localhost:6020' );

ds.login();

// userId
const list = this.ds.record.getList( `Notification/${userId}` );

// id for notification
let id = `Notification/${this.ds.getUid()}`;

let record = this.ds.record.getRecord(id);
record.set( {
  message: 'information'// save notification data
});

list.addEntry(id);
```

Hope it will solve your problem.